# why not replace everything while updating json in a mysql server instead of using any json functions?

Tags: mysql, json, go

I am on mysql 8.0.27-1 and
I have 2 questions actually

1. If i use those `JSON_INSERT` and other function to modify the json data is it replacing the old json data totally or just modifying only some parts which are required ?
2. I tried to find ways to update the json data with golang, everywhere its showing to use those modifying function with this kind of prepared statement

```sql
UPDATE JSONDoc SET Data = JSON_SET(Data, CONCAT('$', ?), CAST(? AS JSON)) WHERE DocID=?
```

but this statement gets difficult when i have **arbitrary** number of json sets to update,

So i was thinking why not update the json data in the program and use the marshaled json data to replace the whole column ? with something like this

```sql
UPDATE JSONDoc SET Data = ? WHERE DocID=?
```

and for contest the maximum json data that i would be having in that column would around 6000 characters and on average 2000 characters

*by characters i mean the length of the marshaled json data*

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. We're glad you're here. Unfortunately, this question can only have opinion-based answers, and this site discourages opinion-based questions. But I'll give my opinion: if that makes your code easier to write, debug, and maintain, then go ahead.

Comment: @BillKarwin thanks for the opinion, 
i didn't thought that this is a opinion based question cause i was asking how the function is handled internally,

altho i did found something regarding to my 1st question few minutes ago
in [this](https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=8963) article